# Nested resources in TastyPie

Tags: django, tastypie

I've tried implementing nested resources in TastyPie, using both examples they provided. One of them fails and I have no idea how or why, and one of them works somewhat.

This is the code snipped I've used:

```
class ParentResource(ModelResource):
    children = fields.ToManyField(ChildResource, 'children')

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/children%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('get_children'), name="api_get_children"),
        ]

    def get_children(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            bundle = self.build_bundle(data={'pk': kwargs['pk']}, request=request)
            obj = self.cached_obj_get(bundle=bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return HttpGone()
        except MultipleObjectsReturned:
            return HttpMultipleChoices("More than one resource is found at this URI.")

        child_resource = ChildResource()
        return child_resource.get_detail(request, parent_id=obj.pk)
```

Now my concrete use case is to have URLs like `/api/v1/schools/<school_id>/departments` and what this would do, is to get a list of `departments` that belong to the `school` with a certain ID. If the school has 1 department, everything works, however if the school has 2+ departments, I get the error message `More than one resource is found at this URI.`

Does TastyPie not support lists of resources when passing a resource ID, or how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace

```
return child_resource.get_detail(request, parent_id=obj.pk)
```

By

```
return child_resource.get_list(request, parent_id=obj.pk)
```